# Sails.js WaterlineORM how to use $and/$or operator in query

Tags: sails.js, waterline

I have a data stored in DB. Here is an example of one document from DB:

```
{
    "year": 2012,
    "indicator": 0
}
```

Other documents contains other years - 2013, 2014 etc. and random "indicator". Now I want to select all document that have data in between 2012 to 2014 range and some indicator. I am working with blueprint sails.js api for passing search queries.

I expect there to be a way to pass two queries and make Waterline select documents that match one (or both) of the queries.

So here is what I have tried (just years for now):

1.

```
 {
        "year": {">=": 2012}
        "year": {"<=": 2014}
 }
```

Here I got only docs that have 2012 as a year.

2.

```
 {
        "year": {">=": 2012, "<=": 2014}
 }
```

Same as 1.

3.

```
 "or": [{
    "year": {">=": 2012}
  }, {
    "year": {"<=": 2014}
  }]
```

Same as 1.

4.

```
 "and": [{
    "year": {">=": 2012}
  }, {
    "year": {"<=": 2014}
  }]
```

Does not return any document.

Question is: how to get documents in some range in waterlineORM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As time has passed and this question was not answered, I'll answer it my self.

This solution does work on the latest version of sails (`1.2.3`) and MySQL DB:

```
await Record.find({
  where: {
    and: [
      {year: {'>': 2005}},
      {year: {'<': 2008}}
    ]
  },
  limit: 3
})
```

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue.... I wish there is such a solution... but I end up using where.

`stuff.find({year:{"<":2014}}).where({year:{">":2012}})`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same question, i think find the solution.

In queries work similarly to mysql 'in queries'. 
Each element in the array is treated as 'or'.

```
Model.find({
  name : ['Walter', 'Skyler']
});
```

[Check this! Waterline Query](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs/blob/master/query-language.md#in-pairs)